# How to store data in workitem using key value pair in TFS using object model

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, workitem

I have heard that there is an api method available in TFS Object model api, through which i can store in the work item using key value pair and this data is not visible in UI as it is not any field value. This data can only be retrieved through api. I have searched but i was not successful up till now. If any one know such type of method so please share it.

My main purpose to store some metadata in it but it should not visible to the User and also user can not update it. Secondly i did not have to use any field, as fields vary from work item to work item and even from Process template to Process template.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you still have any questions about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you mean this link: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/data-storage.

To set a value of key-value you could use this method:

```
VSS.getService(VSS.ServiceIds.ExtensionData).then(function(dataService) {
        // Get value in user scope
        dataService.getValue("userScopedKey", {scopeType: "User"}).then(function(value) {
            console.log("User scoped key value is " + value);
        });
    });
```

This [document](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/vss/sdk/services/extensiondata/extensiondataservice) is the details information about the methods in `VSS.ServiceIds.ExtensionData` service.